# Регистрация класса Bitrix

Tags: php, ооп, битрикс

Пишу модуль.
Пытаюсь подключить свой класс

```
Bitrix\Main\Loader::registerAutoloadClasses(
   "my.space",
   array(
      "My\\Space\\dataMap" => "lib/showdatamap.php",
   )
);
My\Space\dataMap::showDataMap();
```

сам файл с классом

```
namespace My\Space;

  use Bitrix\Main\ModuleManager;
  use Bitrix\Main\Loader;

  class dataMap extends CModule{

    public static function showDataMap(){

    }
  }
```

Выдает ошибку Class 'My\Space\CModule' not found in ....

Что нужно сделать чтобы CModule заработал ?

---

UPD: Решил вопрос
нужно изменить

```
class dataMap extends CModule{
```

на

```
class dataMap extends \CModule{
```

Comment: Вы тут разберитесь что подключаете. У Вас класс `dataMap` при чем тут `CModule` его нет нигде. И именуйте классы с заглавной буквы.

Comment: @NikolajSarry Люди могут подумать что вы тролль. Видимо если я спросил про CModule, то он где-то всё таки есть, не так ли ? И правда, вот же он тут - class dataMap extends \CModule{

Comment: так и показывайте участок где он используется. Как можно помочь, если в приведенном фрагменте нигде нет его упоминания? Телепатов здесь нет.

Comment: @NikolajSarry я задал конкретный вопрос, на конкретном примере, указал на ошибку, куда еще точнее ?

Comment: скорее всего проглядел `extends`. бывает. хорошо что разобрались.